# Angular Material 2 space-between mat-button for mat-menu

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I am trying to create spacing inside my `mat-button` between the button text (`span`) and the button icon (`fa-icon`) that will show my `mat-menu` when clicked. I'm trying to get it to look like this:

[image: Expected result]

I can't seem to get it working at all.

Here's my code:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Participant">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="participantStatusMenu" class="participantStatusBtn">
    <span>{{Participant.status | participantStatus}}</span>
    <fa-icon class="" [icon]="['fas', 'angle-down']" size="lg"></fa-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #participantStatusMenu="matMenu" class="participantStatusMenu">
    <button *ngIf="Participant.status !== 1" mat-menu-item>{{1 | participantStatus}}</button>
    <button *ngIf="Participant.status !== 2" mat-menu-item>{{2 | participantStatus}}</button>
    <button *ngIf="Participant.status !== 3" mat-menu-item>{{3 | participantStatus}}</button>
  </mat-menu>
</td>
```

Comment: Is al little tweak of dom structure acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by:

```
/deep/ .mat-button-wrapper {
  width: 100%;

  span {
    float: left;
  }

  fa-icon {
    float: right;
  }
}
```